# Фон папки в windows

Tags: изображения, ос

На предмете Операционные системы, встретился такой вопрос:

> Измените внешний вид папки "Мои документы" следующим образом: На фон
> папки установите картинку ... (*вопрос продолжается но не суть*)

Обшарив и Яндекс, и Гугл, не смог найти никакого решения которое позволяло бы сделать это стандартными средствами ОС (Windows XP).
Только 2 варианта:

1. Установите ПО
2. Файл desktop.ini

ПО не подходит, сдавать работу нужно на компе препода.
А в desktop.ini нужно прописывать строку не пригодную для запоминания.

```
 [{BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC}]
 IconArea_Image=bg.jpg
```

Может кто знает иные методы?

Comment: http://www.websofthelp.ru/infchan/230-oformlenie-papok-izmenyaem-fon-papki.html

Comment: Как я уже писал я был в поисковиках. и ПО не подходит.
Вы нашли то же что и я: "В Windows стандартными средствами Вы не сможете сменить белый фон в папке, на какую нибудь картинку."
Однако такой вопрос задан, а я почему то не считаю наших преподов тупицами, хотя начинаю сомневаться)

Comment: @Дмитрий Снежко на странице четко прослеживается desktop.ini файл. И иной метод - с помощью программы ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот каноническое описание от Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812003/ru

Править руками desktop.ini иделогически неправильно, потому что это деталь реализации, и с выходом какого-нибудь сервис-пака может поменяться.

<нытьё>
Вообще, я удивлён уровнем заданий в вузе. Я думал, операционные системы -- это про особенности реализации дисковой подсистемы, планировщика и фсё такоэ.
</нытьё>

---

Гугл считает, что штатными средствами добавить картинку нельзя, так что придётся всё же делать хак, основанный на desktop.ini. Из [этой ссылки](http://easy-life.sabza.org/2008/09/change-folder-background-windows-xp/):

> - разрешите показ скрытых файлов в Explorer'е
> - зайдите в каталог, откройте desktop.ini
> - допишите следующие строки:

```
[ExtShellFolderViews]
{BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC}={BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC}
[{BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC}]
IconArea_Image=C:\Windows\Greenstone.bmp
```

> IconArea_Image означает путь к картинке для фона вашего каталога в Explorer'е. Измените путь на правильный.

И да, поскольку это хак, текст `{BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC}` не несёт никакого смысла для нас с вами -- пользователей.

Comment: Колледж, причём только первый семестр.
Проходили только Команды dos, вот эта вот настройка визуальной части windows, терминал Linux, и так же настройка внешнего вида Linux...
В общем действительно, один бред.

Что то вы много строк написали, работает и с теми что я писал в самом вопросе, я уже проверял этот способ, в любом случае спасибо.

Comment: `не несёт никакого смысла для нас с вами` – почему не несёт? Это идентификатор дополнения (*плагина*, если угодно) Windows Explorer, способного отображать фоновую картинку.

Comment: @Arhad: Ну да, но для пользователей это не должно быть читаемо и легко понимаемо, правильно ведь?